# How do you declare a string array of unknown size?

Tags: java, arrays, string, initialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Declaring an array of unknown size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447981/declaring-an-array-of-unknown-size)

I'm working in Java and I am trying to input a sentence into a string array. I am tokenizing it and determining the word count. However, I need to add each word into a string array in order to determine if there are duplicates or not. I am not sure how to initialize my array if I don't know the word count until later in the program.

```
  //Declares variables
  Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
  int withoutdup = 0, wordCount = 0;
  String line, word; 
  StringTokenizer tokenizer;
  List<String> sentence = ArrayList<String>;

  //Asks user for input
  System.out.println ("Please enter text. Enter DONE to finish.");
  line = scan.next();


  //Tokenizes the string and counts the number of character and words
while (!line.equals("DONE"))
 {
     tokenizer = new StringTokenizer (line);
     while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
     {
        word = tokenizer.nextToken();
        wordCount++;
        sentence += word; 
     }
     line = scan.next();
 }
```

Comment: then you should use an ArrayList instead, and at the end you still can convert to an array...

Answer (score 32):

Use an `ArrayList` instead

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

it grows automatically.

To check for the duplicates, you can utilize a `Set` (`HashSet`), it doesn't allow duplicate elements.

**Update**

I see a couple of problem in your code:

```
List<String> sentence = ArrayList<String>;
```

You are missing the `new` after `=`.

```
sentence += word;
```

That only would work if `sentence` was a `String`. It's a `List` so you should use `List.add` method there

```
sentence.add(word);
```

Also now `wordCount++;` is redundant `sentence.size()` will tell you how many words.

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty new to this but this is what I have in regards to inputting the sentence: 
      System.out.println ("Please enter text. Enter DONE to finish.");
      line = scan.next();
    while (!line.equals("DONE"))
     {
         tokenizer = new StringTokenizer (line);
         while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
         {
            word = tokenizer.nextToken();
            wordCount++;
         }
         line = scan.next();
     }
how do I declare an array list because List<String> sentence = ArrayList<String>(); is not working?

Comment: @user1755178: Can you update the question itself, with the code?

Comment: @user1755178: I added some comments about your code, see the update.

Answer (score 6):

just see the below example, you will get the idea about how to declare a string array of unknown size.

First, use ArrayList to store the strings and each time call the .add method the ArrayList size increases by one element. When you're filling the ArrayList, use ArrayList size() method and create your String array and size it from. But make sure that each element in an ArrayList is an Object that’s why you need to convert each element to a String.

Example:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

for( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ )

list.add( "stuff" );

String[] strArray = new String[ list.size() ];

for( int j = 0; j < strArray.length; j++ )

strArray[ j ] = list.get( j ).toString();
```

Hope this will help you. It’s just one way, but I think there might be another more efficient way through you can do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Use a **dynamic** structure which can shrink and grow as needed, `ArrayList` would be a good choice, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible, arrays are constant in length. Its better to use `java.util.List` implementation like `ArrayList,LinkedList` etc...

If you want to persist with array then you can use such function to resize your array but again here it will create a new array with new size and copy previous arrays value.

```
private static Object resizeArray (Object oldArray, int newSize) {
   int oldSize = java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(oldArray);
   Class elementType = oldArray.getClass().getComponentType();
   Object newArray = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(
         elementType, newSize);
   int preserveLength = Math.min(oldSize, newSize);
   if (preserveLength > 0)
      System.arraycopy(oldArray, 0, newArray, 0, preserveLength);
   return newArray; 
}
```